# How to check for a number in AngularJS template HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Something weird is happening and I don't why.

In my application for certain conditions, some values are passed as undefined.

So, if a variable is computed like this

```
selectedPricingMappingObj.forEach(function(server){
    .....
    .....
    vm.totalOfCostCalculationItems += server.details.price;
```

where `price` is `undefined`.

It shows me `NaN` when price `undefined`.

But when `price` is `defined', 
    angular.isNumber(vm.totalOfCostCalculationItems) returns`true`.

[image]

But when I try the same in `UI`.

```
<td style="text-align:left;"
    ng-if="angular.isNumber(vm.totalOfCostCalculationItems)">
  <b>${{vm.totalOfCostCalculationItems.toFixed(2)}}<b>
</td>
```

it shows nothing. Why is that?

Comment: why don't you use parseInt to convert it to number instead of adding a check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`angular.isNumber` won't work in `ng-if` because `angular` is not a part of the `$scope`. It's just a global variable. If you really need to use `angular.isNumber` in the view, you need to make it a part of your ViewModel:

**Controller**

`vm.isNumber = angular.isNumber;`

**View**

`<td style="text-align:left;" ng-if="vm.isNumber(vm.totalOfCostCalculationItems)">`

---

**Edit**

To answer the question about `angular.isNumber(NaN)` returning true which appeared in the comments, I've made a quick search and found this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/701 . Although it's a bit illogical to me as well, it seems that this behaviour is consistent with JavaScript standards as `typeof NaN === 'number'` is also resolved to true. If you want to avoid such behaviour, you need to check the number both with `angular.isNumber` and `!isNaN`:

```
vm.isNumber = function(number) {
    return angular.isNumber(number) && !isNaN(number);
}
```

Comment: If it shows as `NaN` in console but if It do `vm.isNumber(vm.totalOfCostCalculationItems)` it shows true. Why is that ?

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know about this. I've made a quick search and modified the answer.